# SonarQube upgrade to 6.7.1 version : Old plugin Supported while upgrade

Tags: sonarqube

We are upgrading the Sonarqube from 5.6.3 to 6.7, our current Sonarqube has old plugin that we are using check the list below.

1. SonarJava sonar-java-plugin-4.6.0.8784
2. SOnarC# sonar-csharp-plugin-5.10.1.1411
3. SonarJS sonar-javascript-plugin-2.21.0.4409
4. SonarPlSql sonar-plsql-plugin-2.9.0.901
5. Ldap sonar-ldap-plugin-2.0
6. SonarPHP sonar-php-plugin-2.10.0.2087
7. PMD sonar-pmd-plugin-2.6
8. SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2
9. SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3
10. Sonar XML sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.2.885

When we try to setup SonarQube 6.7 all the above plugin works fine.

So My question is while upgrading from 5.6.3 to 6.7.1 Could we face any issues because of the Plugin.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Version 6.7.1 is a minor release and its plugin API has exactly the same behavior as 6.7. For this reason you can safely upgrade to 6.7.1 without changing plugins. 
Note that, as a rule of thumb, exceptional breaking changes are listed in [upgrade notes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading).